# When integrating, what are all the exact requirements for a substitution to be valid?

Tags: calculus, integration

There are many examples on this site of substitutions that are not valid for varying reasons. But there are probably many more that I still don't know of.

When working with definite and indefinite integrals, what are all the rules for valid substitutions?

(It would also be nice to have explanations but this is not necessary.)

Comment: I think all monotone derivable functions $f$ which derivate doesn't vanish.

Comment: It's best to remember the rule of substitution. There are some variations of the rule and hence it may be described differently in various textbooks. Follow the one prescribed in your textbook. Apostol gives it as: $\int_{g(a)} ^{g(b)} f(x) \, dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(g(t)) g'(t) \, dt$ if $g'$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ and $f$ is continuous on $g([a, b]) $.